# Why SwiftUI Limited `@ViewBuilder` parameters count to 10?

Tags: swift, swiftui

```swift
@available(iOS 13.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
extension ViewBuilder {

    public static func buildBlock<C0, C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, C7, C8, C9>(_ c0: C0, _ c1: C1, _ c2: C2, _ c3: C3, _ c4: C4, _ c5: C5, _ c6: C6, _ c7: C7, _ c8: C8, _ c9: C9) -> TupleView<(C0, C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, C7, C8, C9)> where C0 : View, C1 : View, C2 : View, C3 : View, C4 : View, C5 : View, C6 : View, C7 : View, C8 : View, C9 : View
}
```

In the source code, `ViewBuilder` max parameters was limited to 10.

Comment: Let's say they increase it to 11, you'd ask "Why did they limit it to 11?" wouldn't you? When you have more than ten views, you should consider extracting some of them as a separate view.

Comment: Yes...If you want more then 10 then you can use Group inside the VStack or HStack

Comment: Even with 10 views in one builder the code becomes very complicated and compiler often rejects it, so usually, and as a good practice, we use even less amount of subviews. The smaller views you have the faster they are compiled (and compiled in general). So I'd say that 10 views are more than enough in ViewBuilder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly [variadic generics are not yet supported](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/docs/GenericsManifesto.md#variadic-generics), so it was not possible to declare this function with a variadic input arguments (which means that you could pass in any number of input arguments).

Most probably 10 seemed like a good rule of thumb, since if you need more subviews, you can always break up your view builder into several smaller functions.

Comment: This might improve in an upcoming Swift version: https://forums.swift.org/t/pitching-the-start-of-variadic-generics/51467